# Grey out a preference in settings android

Tags: android, settings, preferences, user-experience

I want to grey out one of the panes in the settings, like this (bottom preference)

(note: I edited the design image as not to give away info about the app. I've signed a non-disclosure agreement and don't want to get fired)

[image: like this]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you try `preference_instance.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: but I want it enabled also.All I need to change is that it should be greyed out. We had a user-experience guy tell us to do this, I'm just following orders.

Comment: Yes, that should be okay. Just call `pref_inst.setEnabled(true | false)` depending on your need.

Answer (score 2):

Set setShouldDisableView(true). Then, set setEnabled(false). This should make the item appear disabled (grey) and not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to the Answer of RamiReddy, is a bit old so i will put below the updated one. I hope will help someone.

This is worked for me. My code:

```
Preference key_remove_ads = findPreference(getString(R.string.key_remove_ads_));
            key_remove_ads.setEnabled(false);
            key_remove_ads.setShouldDisableView(true);
```

And this is my xml:

```
android:defaultValue="@string/remove_ads_title_small"
android:key="@string/key_remove_ads_"
android:summary="@string/remove_ads_title_small"
android:title="@string/remove_ads_title" />
```